# Issue with jQuery images resizing to fit modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Okay, this one has me confused as hell (I've spent hours trying to figure it out) so I am hoping perhaps a fresh set of eyes might be able to spot the culprit easier than I can.

The page in question is here: http://centerpointesigns.com/dev/portfolio/

Go to that page on a desktop and open the GLA Building link (underlined).

You'll see that the gallery (using a plugin called Envira Gallery for WordPress) is super, super tiny and I know that this is because it can't determine the size of the modal it's within (which is a plugin called Easy Modal for WordPress).

I've added the following code to the functions.js file assuming it would fix it, but no suck luck:

```
// Prevent resizing of Envira Galleries with Easy Modal plugin
$('.emodal').on('emodalBeforeOpen', function() {
$(window).triggerHandler("resize");
});
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here? Seems like it should be easy and I must be overlooking something obvious.

Comment: Yes, they do indeed have the desired size if you resize the browser once it's opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error: "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" in functions.js, line 56.

I replaced $ by jQuery, and your gallery now looks great :-)

```
jQuery('.emodal').on('emodalBeforeOpen', function() {  
  jQuery(window).triggerHandler("resize");
});
```

Comment: That did the trick! I didn't even catch that until you just pointed it out.

Comment: Classic example of Ockham's Razor at it's finest. Thanks a million! I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me. It says I have to wait 3 minutes.